# Error during redirecting large files in Django backend from Angular frontend to the Hadoop

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, hadoop, django-rest-framework

I build web application with Angular 6 frontend, Django 1.11 backend and Hadoop 3.1. I need to send files of any size and format in the fastest possible way from Angular 6 frontend to the Hadoop via Django backend. My method in Django looks line shown below. Everything seems to be working fine with small files in different formats. However when I try to upload larger files I get the error shown at the bottom. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
def post(self, request):

    key = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').split()[1]

    user_id = Token.objects.get(key=key).user_id

    user_name = User.objects.get(id=user_id).username

    upload_file(request.FILES['file'], user_name)

    url = 'http://192.168.0.12:9864/webhdfs/v1/user/' + str(user_name) + '/' + str(request.FILES['file']) + '?op=CREATE&user.name=myuser&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false'

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

**ERROR**

```
django_1  | Internal Server Error: /cloud/
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
django_1  |     chunked=chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
django_1  |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
django_1  |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
django_1  |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
django_1  |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
django_1  |     self.send(chunk)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
django_1  |     self.sock.sendall(data)
django_1  | BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
django_1  | 
django_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1  | 
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
django_1  |     timeout=timeout
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
django_1  |     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
django_1  |     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
django_1  |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
django_1  |     chunked=chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
django_1  |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
django_1  |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
django_1  |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
django_1  |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
django_1  |     self.send(chunk)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
django_1  |     self.sock.sendall(data)
django_1  | urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
django_1  | 
django_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1  | 
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
django_1  |     response = get_response(request)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
django_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
django_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
django_1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
django_1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
django_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
django_1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
django_1  |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/code/backend/views.py", line 38, in post
django_1  |     upload_file(request.FILES['file'], user_name)
django_1  |   File "/code/backend/hdfs.py", line 8, in upload_file
django_1  |     response = requests.put(url + ':9870/webhdfs/v1/user/' + str(user_name) + '/' + str(file) + '?op=CREATE&user.name=myuser&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false' , data=file, headers={'content-type':'application/octet-stream'})
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 126, in put
django_1  |     return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
django_1  |     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
django_1  |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
django_1  |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 495, in send
django_1  |     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
django_1  | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
django_1  | [29/Sep/2018 15:05:09] "POST /cloud/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17123
django_1  | [29/Sep/2018 15:05:09] "GET /cloud/ HTTP/1.1" 200 34
django_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
django_1  |   """)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII I updated the question. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: yes I have two ideas that I'm going to post as a potential answer because idk if I have enough space here

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what your issue is, which due to the large size of the file. For smaller files, the upload speed is most likely something small enough that it is not really noticeable, whether it's milliseconds or even seconds. For files that are much larger, though, the speed can take significantly longer based on the file size, as well as speed and latency and a bunch of other network things.

All of that is said because you don't return a response to the post request until the upload is done. If the upload process takes too long, the connection is going to close (aka the connection aborted error you see), which then means the upload process is going to fail as well.

One option would be to increase the total time the connection would stay open, which is probably not the best solution for a production system with a bunch of users for various reasons. There would be various ways to do that, based on the overall system configuration.

The other option would be to do the upload in the background using, for example, [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which would allow the upload process to occur and then allow you to close the connection and return a response to your user. Based on your code, you would have to change the way you handle the problem, and you can use celery and/or websockets to return when the upload is completed. These are just my thoughts, though.

Best of luck!